# knockout js loop through the elements to increment the data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, carousel

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
```

I would like to reduce the redundancy of this code by using knockout js. Here is what I have tried and I am very new to Knockout js. The below code does not work and I think statically defining the class names is creating a problem and I would like to use ko.computed function so as to get rid of defining the elements. Any help or code examples is appreciated.

```
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" data-bind="foreach: items">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-bind='attr: { "data-slide-to": slide, class: className }'></li>
        </ol>
        function AppViewModel() 
        {   
           this.items= [
            { slide: ko.observable(0), className: ko.observable("active") },
            { slide: ko.observable(1), className: ko.observable("inactive") },
            { slide: ko.observable(2), className: ko.observable("inactive") },
            { slide: ko.observable(3), className: ko.observable("inactive") },
            { slide: ko.observable(4), className: ko.observable("inactive") }

            ];
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's a little more to an 'item' than just slide index and whether it's active. For the purpose of the example, I'll assume they have a property 'id'.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-bind="click: $parent.setActiveItem, attr: { 'data-slide-to': $index() }, css: { 'active': id === $parent.activeItemId() }"></li>
</ol>

function AppViewModel() 
{   
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        { id: 23 },
        { id: 47 },
        { id: 13 },
        { id: 6 },
        { id: 3 }
    ]);
    self.activeItemId = ko.observable(self.items()[0].id);
    self.setActiveItem = function (item) {
        self.activeItemId(item.id);
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

To change slides, I added a function to the viewmodel `setActiveItem` that changes the `activeItemId` observable. This will set the `active` class to that slide. You can use the function as a click event handler, or whatever interaction pattern you want to change slides.

I used `$index` from knockout instead of your slide observable, you get that one for free :)

Edit: I've put it all together in a JSFiddle for you to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/74jwZ/1/

Click on a slide to make it active.